# Lock the file while reading and writing

Tags: php, file, fopen

I have a file which stores some value. Users can add stuff to that file and the counter in that file is updated. But if two users open the file, they'll get the same counter (`$arr['counter']`). What should I do? Maybe can I lock the file for one user and release the lock after he updates the counter and add some stuff back to the file? Or PHP already locks the file once is opened and I don't need to worry? Here's my current code:

```
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
    fclose($handle);       

    $arr = json_decode($contents);

    //Add stuff here to $arr and update counter $arr['counter']++

    $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, json_encode($arr));   
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing that'd typically be done with a sequence object in a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has the [`flock`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) function which will lock the file before writing to it, example,

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);       

$arr = json_decode($contents);

//Add stuff here to $arr and update counter $arr['counter']++

$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX))
{
    fwrite($handle, json_encode($arr));
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN);        
}
else
{
    // couldn't lock the file
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I need to lock before reading the file too, because I don't want to have the same counter for both users.

Comment: @hey I would consider doing this silly here, as there are likely better ways (read: databases), but if you'd really like to see when/where locks needs to acquired (as well as when syncs must occur), read the SQLite locking documentation.

Comment: @hey Well consider rephrasing that question in a different way: What advantage is there of *not* using a database here? (And when I say database, I do not strictly mean an RDBMS or MySQL!)

Comment: @pst: It will be faster in my situation I think.

Comment: @hey Haha. Hah. Yeah, uhm .. no. The only exception that I can imagine is the PHP process is not recycled and then *nanoseconds* of start-up time *might* be saved. But this approach will likely "not be faster". Going for micro-*imagined*-speed improvements like this is a waste of time. No test case -> no performance issue. Then again, I've done all this square wheel stuff before so, enjoy!